# "no space" error when using shell script with ulimit stack at 32K

Tags: shell, ksh

The objective is to collect information about top 10 process using memory. This will help to identify the top user - over a period of time. The following script is being used. But, it stops after a period of time with "no space" error after reaching 32K limit.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

while :
do
    today=`date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"`
    top=`svmon -P`
    sum=`svmon -P -t10 -O summary=basic`
    echo "$today" >> svmonps.out
    echo "$top" >> svomonps.out
    echo "$sum" >> svmonps.out
    sleep 30
done
exit 0
```

Current ulimit -a setting for stack (kbytes) is 32768. Can we modify the script to continue inspite of ulimit restriction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can give up using those variables & sub-shells.
run `date` and `svmon` directly to your file, or even better to the standard output, and append to `svmonps.out` when you call your script.

check this out:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

while :; do
    date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"
    svmon -P
    svmon -P -t10 -O summary=basic
    sleep 30
done
exit 0
```

And when you run your script run it like this to append to your file:

> $ myScript >> svmonps.out